# Question on proof where I should only be using postulates

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

Looking at this proof, I proved that AE is congruent to EB and DF is congruent to FC by the definition of the midpoint. I also know AB is congruent to DE, but I don’t know where to go from there. Usually I would use the subtraction postulate, but doing AB-AE would give me BE, not EA. Any suggestions would be appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4L75.jpg)

Comment: $\overline{AB}$ is not congruent to $\overline{DE}$. Did you mean $\overline{CD}$?